# static reference from class to non-static method in data base adapter can't be done

Tags: java, android, static-methods

As it is in the topic I'm still new to android. I was following some tutorial about filtering text and after finishing eclipse gave me this error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method tchCountriesByName(String) from the type DBAdapter
```

I was looking in other examples but anywhere I couldn't find a match to my case.

```
  myCursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
         public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
             return new DBAdapter(list.this).fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString()); //here's the error
         }
     });
 }
```

here the method it's refering to. I tried putting "static" everywhere in the code where I could but i still doesn't work.

```
 public Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) {
      Log.w(TAG, inputText);
      Cursor c = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
         KEY_NAME, KEY_COUNTRY, KEY_REGION},
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
      c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
         KEY_NAME, KEY_COUNTRY, KEY_REGION},
         KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, null, null);
      }
      if (c != null) {
       c.moveToFirst();
      }
      return c;

     }
```

thank you for your input.

Comment: "*I'm still new to android*" are you also new to Java? Do you know what `static` means in Java?

Comment: You should learn the basics of Java and OOP before you try to build apps.  This is first week in school stuff.

Comment: @Pshemo that I don't need to create instance for it, but I couldn't find out how to adjust dbadapter method and make it static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make `fetchCountriesByName()` method `static`.

```
public static Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) {
  // your method implementation
}
```

Then you have to use all variable inside that method `static`.

So `easy option` is create an `instance` of that class and call your `method`.

Eg:

```
 public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
    return new DBAdapter().fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString()); 
 }
```

Important point is you should know where should use `static` and where should not? putting `static` without a meaning may cause issues.

Edit: seems to be you are new to `Java`. when you create an instance of `DBAdapter` there should be no argument constructor to use `new DBAdapter()`. Else you should go with correct `constructor` of `DBAdapter`.

Comment: Then it says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field db" to exequte query

Comment: @kTN then you can go with my second option

Comment: "The constructor DBAdapter() is undefined" when passing contexdoesn't work I'll see what happens when I pass null

Comment: @kTN i have add more points to my answer. Those may help you to fixed the issue. you should learn `Java` basic first. Else you may face this kind of issues regularly.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. I'm reading now "thinking in Java". True I'm new, but always I try to find out on my own, if I can't I ask for guidance. The thing is that I went throu all the tutorial and couldn't find why it worked for the guy and it doesn't for me. http://sathishrmr.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/android-listview-using-cursoradapter.html. I have a constructor in this class that displays data from db in a listview and the same constructor should be filtering it.

Comment: @kTN you are always welcome. You can reach us(me) when ever you are stuck while you are trying something... Make sure come up with your try when you are looking some help.

Comment: I'm not one of this type "do everything for me" I try my best first looking for answers and solutions, but it's first time since the beginning of my short android adventure when I'm stuck and didn't find a way out for a long time so I decided to look for help. My edit shares all the code connected to this subject and still I can find the solution I'd appreciate more direct help :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use instance of your DBAdapter, or make fetchCountriesByName static.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
return new DBAdapter().fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString());
```

instead of:

```
 return DBAdapter.fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, later it asks to define it, but I suppose it's more than I can do right now at least.